# How to store settings information for user?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I need for my application to be able to store simple settings like Display Name, Localization, Color scheme etc for the users as  key:value string pairs.

A lot of the examples online suggest just creating a custom "Settings" object, is this the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Custom settings is not an object. It is a feature in Salesforce. You can view and create custom settings under Setup>Develop>Custom Settings. And yes, it is the best of storing org config settings.

For more information about custom settings, you can refer to https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en

Answer (score 1):

Custom settings are a special type of metadata whose data can be retrieved without using SOQL query. This can be used to store Organization wide configuration settings which won't change. We can say Custom settings are like constants whose values doesn't change.

Custom settings records are considered as data and need to be created/migrated in Target org while migrating from Source org.

Now we have something called Custom Metadata type whose data records are considered as metadata than data like Custom settings data records. So you can migrate the data records of Custom Metadata type from one org to other using deployment tools.

Reference - [Custom Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm&language=en_US) and [Custom Metadata Types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm)

Comment: What if i want the user to be able to change the setting on demand, would this still be the right way to go?

Comment: Why would you give normal user the power to change your organization constants. System Admins will have access to change it but not users.

Comment: Well it's going to be settings relevant to the user, not to the org, I think people may be misunderstanding my question

Comment: If you could add your use case bit elaborately to your question it will help us. By looking at your comment, your best bet would be creating a custom object with fields as your keys required. Users can create and update recorda .